# SmsUserConsentAPI to read sender name with first two letter dynamic

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-api-client

I am using UserConsentAPI for reading SMS in Android App, In that there is a method

> startSmsUserConsent()

In this method we need to pass sender Number/Name, For example my sender name is **ViCARE**,
I received VT-ViCARE, BT-ViCARE, AD-ViCare like that each time.First two character of sender name is dynamically changed. If I give below like that reading particular sms from "VT-ViCARE" it works fine, How to read the sender contain "??-ViCARE" using User Consent API?

> smsRetrieverClient.startSmsUserConsent("VT-ViCARE")

Comment: I am not sure I understand totally. How do you read sms from "VT-ViCARE"? Can you give that statement where you read it? I suppose you can simple using String 'contains("")' method.

Comment: @SarahKhan In startSmsUserConsent() function you can pass sender number, In that I passed that name "VT-ViCARE" it works.

Comment: you can call it with null to retrieve any sender 
`startSmsUserConsent(null)`

Comment: What happens when you only send ViCARE?

Comment: @SarahKhan nothing filtered

Comment: @AndreiStoicescu null I know, but I am asking particular sender name

Comment: Just use null or set contact permissions to get recent contacts to get the sender name and match the Strings leaving two dynamic character. If confirmed use the sender name.

Answer (score 0):

I did research a lot but currently can't find an exact answer to your question but here is a workaround. How about you call the String's contains method, check if the sender name contains ViCARE, and then pass it to startSmsUserConsent ?

```
Boolean sender = "YourDynamicSender".contains("ViCARE");
if (sender) {
    val task1 = SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("YourDynamicSender")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all of these lines to your code and you are good to go.

```
SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("VT-ViCARE");
SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("BT-ViCARE");
SmsRetriever.getClient(applicationContext).startSmsUserConsent("AD-ViCARE");
```